# submit video feed to itune

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, app-store-connect

Is there any way to submit Video Feed to itune directly without iTunes application(like by API) manually.
I am searching a way to submit feed or podcast directly from ROR application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible todo this from the iTunes API. Take a look at this [project](https://code.google.com/p/itunes-remote-control-server/), it provides command line utils for controlling iTunes. The source file [macosx_itunescontroller.rb](https://code.google.com/p/itunes-remote-control-server/source/browse/lib/itunesController/macosx_itunescontroller.rb) has a method called addFilesToLibrary() that adds tracks to the iTunes library. If your on windows, then this is a version of this source file for windows as well.

If this does not quite what you need, it should be possible todo something similar.